# Reparameterizing PDF to get components of exponential family

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, exponential-family

For the following problem, I am trying to identify the components of the exponential family in the form:

$\exp(y\theta - b(\theta))/a(\phi) + c(y; \phi)$

Namely, I need to identify the $\theta, b(\theta), a(\phi), c(y; \phi)$ and canonical link for the distribution that allows it to be in the exponential family. I was given the following text:

[image]

I've done this with other distributions, but the fact that I need to reparameterize is throwing me off. I'm not sure what I should be doing to be able to show the components or where the new parameters come into play. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: There must be a typographical error in your expression of the exponential form.  After you fix it, *take logarithms:* compare its log to the log of the NB distribution.  That requires just a bit of algebra.

Comment: I'm more confused about how to go through the reparameterization process. It's not entirely clear to me what I need to do to reparameterize this. Do I just re-express r in terms of mu and pi in terms of k and plug those values in?

Comment: Almost: you need to find a formula for the current parameter $(r,\pi)$ in terms of the new parameter $(k,\mu).$  Thus, each of $r$ and $\pi$ may be a function of *both* the new parameters.

Comment: Okay. So then just to make sure I'm on the right track, if I re-express these parameters, I get =k/+k and r=k. Is that correct? Then I just plug it into the original density function and solve as I normally word by taking the log and exponentiating?